# Using JRadioButtons with a derby database

Tags: java, swing, jframe, derby, jradiobutton

I am trying to use the user's selection of a JRadioButton as part of a SELECT query for a derby database. For some reason, when I click the search button (called diffSearchbtn), nothing happens. What should be happening is that the SELECT query puts all the entries that match the criteria of the radio button into a JTable on a panel called dispPanel.

Here is the code for the method that assigns a string based on what button the user clicks.

```
private String tagValid()
{
    String diff = "";

    if (dEasybtn.isSelected())
    {
        diff = "EASY";
        System.out.println("easy");
    }

    else if (dMedbtn.isSelected())
    {
        diff = "MEDIUM";
        System.out.println("medium");
    }


    else if (dHardbtn.isSelected())
    {
        diff = "HARD";
        System.out.println("hard");
    }

    else
    {
      diff = null;
    }

   return null;

}
```

Here is the code that is meant to display the form:

```
private void diffSearchbtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              

    if(tagValid()!=null)
    {
    String q = String.format("Select* from Gabby.PData where DIFFICULTY = '%d'", tagValid());
    ResultSet res = Backend.query(q);
    guiTable.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(res));

    int counter = 3;

            try 
            {
                while (res.next()) {
                    counter++;
                    System.out.println("increasing counter");
                }
            } 
            catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(WikiPlantGUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

            if (counter == 0) 
            {
                basePanel.removeAll();
                basePanel.add(NoMatchPanel);
                basePanel.repaint();
                basePanel.revalidate();
            }

            else
            {
                basePanel.removeAll();
                basePanel.add(dispPanel);
                basePanel.repaint();
                basePanel.revalidate();
            }

    }  
}
```

Here is the code from the class Backend:

```
public static ResultSet query(String q) 
{
    try {
        System.out.println("a query");
        Statement stat = myConObj.createStatement();
        ResultSet res = stat.executeQuery(q);
        return res;
    } 
    catch (SQLException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace(); // tells what the error is
        return null; // returns nothing
    }
}
```

[GUI screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJCqv.jpg)

There are no error messages, and the program otherwise runs perfectly. Any idea on what's going wrong?

Comment: Does it print any of the println messages? Maybe `tagValid()` is returning `null`, and so you're not running any of this code at all?

Comment: I tested it and it seems to stop working in the try- catch statement because the String "increasing counter" is not printed out. How do I stop tagValid() from returning null?

Comment: If the code you pasted is accurate in your question, then it looks like the last line of `tagValid()` should be `return diff;`, not `return null;`

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Hard code data to replace the DB. 2) Use a [`CardLayout`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html) as shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5786005/418556). 3) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently.